# Windows Explorer folder is not changing into General view

Tags: windows, windows-10, windows-explorer

I had a folder that had a wav file in it, and the Explorer view for the folder (the columns at the top of the folder) became automatically customized for music view

I want it to go back to the column shown in a General folder view. I have gone to Properties -> Customize -> General Items many times, reopened folder, restarted computer, but it keeps on staying at the Music view.

[image]

Is this a bug in windows 10? How do I force the folder view to change to General Items?

Windows version:
Edition Windows 10 Pro
Version 21H2
OS build    19044.2728
Experience  Windows Feature Experience Pack 120.2212.4190.0

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the solution is to change to "Documents" view instead of "General Items". Selecting "General Items" will make windows choose the folder template based on folder contents, and if there is a wav file in it the columns will change to reflect that. Selecting "Documents" will change columns to the default values (Name, Date, Modified, Type, Size), regardless of folder content.